# How do I perform multiple SQL queries using a single MySQL connection?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form4
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim Command1 As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=asdf1j2k;database=abeetha"
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim sql As String
            Dim sql1 As String
            sql = "SELECT SurName FROM a"
            sql1 = "select UserName from a"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
            Command1 = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
            reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
            reader = Command1.ExecuteReader()
            If (reader.Read()) Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows().Count - 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = reader.GetString("SurName")
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = reader.GetString("UserName")
                Next
            End If
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Make your code readable and easy to understand. And read this [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In this case the easiest solution is to use a single SQL query:

```
sql = "SELECT SurName,UserName FROM a"
```

Then you'd only need one `MySqlCommand`:

```
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
```

If you want to do the two different SQL queries separately, you should also create a separate `MySqlDataReader`:

```
Dim reader1 As MySqlDataReader
```

Then:

```vb
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
'Note that you used the sql variable instead of sql1
Command1 = New MySqlCommand(sql1, MysqlConn)
reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
reader1 = Command1.ExecuteReader()
```

Then when reading the values you should use the corresponding `reader`:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = reader.GetString("SurName")
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = reader1.GetString("UserName")
```

---

**General coding note**: please use consistent and understandable naming, because using `sql` and `sql1` is not clear at all and it also is easy to create mistakes (like the error you made, using `sql` instead of `sql`). Also the use of capitalized variable names (e.g. `COMMAND`) is not common and can create confusion. See for example the [Visual Basic Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> if you execute multiple query with ; as last u can use for example

```
        sql = "SELECT SurName FROM TABLE1;select NAME from TABLE2"
        MySqlCommand COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```